# Countdown time background and open the app after finishing countdow.

Tags: java, android, admob

I see some app, when I click their Interstitial add they are countdown time and showing time with Toast while I was in my defult browser after clicking the ad. And after 1-2 minute they again take me to their app and giving reward. How to do this type of task?? 
I checked when i clcik on ad onAdLeftApplication method is called. I try to set a countdown timer inside this method and on onFinish methoa of countdown timer I try to open the app using intent but its not working. How to do this type of work???

Answer (score 0):

You make timer in activity\fragment A, then start activity\fragment B, so previous one stops, and nothing keeps working there. You need to use service. Create a timer there, so you have a context to update info in app.